# JavaScript. Как сделать что бы Event PageX и PageY отсчитывался в пределах блока?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Всем привет. Допустим есть блок `<div id="block"></div>`. Как сделать что бы положение курсора начинало свой отчет только внутри блока, и только в его пределах. То есть когда курсор находится в левом верхнем углу этого блока, результат был `X:1, Y:1`.

Comment: Нужно, видимо, вычитать расстояние между верхом страницы и верхней границы `div`. Так же с левой стороной.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно вычитать из положения курсора положение элемента. Положение элемента узнаём функцией [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://learn.javascript.ru/coordinates):

```js
var block = document.querySelector('#block');

block.onmousemove = function(event) {
  var mpos_left = event.pageX,
      mpos_top = event.pageY
      
  var mpos_block_left = mpos_left - this.getBoundingClientRect().left,
      mpos_block_top = mpos_top - this.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      
  this.innerHTML = 'Left: '+mpos_block_left+'; Top: '+mpos_block_top;
};
```

```css
#block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="block"></div>
```